# A problem about eigenvalues in a quadratic form

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the eigenvalues of the matrix of the bilinear form corresponding to the quadratic form: 
$$Q(x)=x_1^{2}-4x_1x_2+2x_1x_3+4x_2^{2}+x_3^{2}$$
The characteristic polynomial gives me:

$$6x^{2}-x^{3}-4x-4$$

after I computed the matrix Q:

1-x   ;   -2    ;    1

-2    ;   4-x   ;    0

1     ;     0   ;    1-x

How can I determine the eigenvalues?

Thank you for your understanding and I wait forward your response!

Comment: What is the matrix of $Q$ you have computed ?

Comment: Using WolframAlpha, your polynomials has roots approximately equal to $-0.53,1.48,5.05$. The answers are not particularly nice.  Can you tell us where you came across this? Is this a question for your class?  What exactly is it that they are asking about $Q$? Perhaps you are not meant to explicitly compute the eigenvalues.

Comment: Yes,it says to determine the proper values.And it's a question from my geometry book.

Comment: And what can I do about this?It says to determine the proper vectors also.

Comment: @Adrian Well they're [pretty awful](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=eigenvalues+%7B%7B1%2C-2%2C1%7D%2C%7B-2%2C4%2C0%7D%2C%7B1%2C0%2C1%7D%7D) in this case.

Comment: On the other hand, it is quite easy to find a matrix $P$ of determinant $1$ such that $P^T M P = D$ is diagonal, with $M$ your 3 by 3 matrix, but $P^T P \neq I.$ The diagonal entries are not fixed though, I don't know what "proper values" means. But you have three irrational real eigenvalues again and are in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casus_irreducibilis  and nothing useful can be done by hand.  So, we are back to the source of this and your other questions.  What geometry book?